# How to write fancy-indented multi-line brace expansion in Bash?

Tags: bash, indentation, curly-braces, brace-expansion

I'm dealing with a line such :

```
mkdir -p "$DEST_ROOT_PATH/"{"$DEST_DIR1","$DEST_DIR2", ..., "$DEST_DIRN"}
```

This line is quite long. I want to cut it so its width will fit into a 80 columns line. I tried to escape an end of line with a backslash, but space alignement breaks the expansion :

```
$ echo "ha"{a,b,\
>           c}
ha{a,b, c}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use this disgusting hack.

```
echo "ha"{a,b,\
> `      `c}
```

It opens a subshell with nothing in it, but gets processed before the expansion so the expansion just sees an empty space

Comment: it may be disgusting, but it is quite clever!

Comment: Thanks you, Accepted. Disgusting but accepted. Now I wonder if i'll use it, I'm facing an horrible choice. :)

Answer (score 6):

This is the normal behaviour. From the Bash reference manual:

> [3.5.1 Brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion)
>
> Brace expansion is a mechanism by which arbitrary strings may be
>   generated. This mechanism is similar to filename expansion (see
>   Filename Expansion), but the filenames generated need not exist.
>   **Patterns to be brace expanded take the form of an optional preamble, followed by either a series of comma-separated strings or a sequence
>   expression between a pair of braces, followed by an optional
>   postscript**. The preamble is prefixed to each string contained within
>   the braces, and the postscript is then appended to each resulting
>   string, expanding left to right.

Brace expansion does not allow spaces in between elements that get placed between `\` and the next element in the following line.

And why? Because it gets removed when being processed:

> [3.1.2.1 Escape Character](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Escape-Character)
>
> A non-quoted backslash ‘\’ is the Bash escape character. It preserves
>   the literal value of the next character that follows, with the
>   exception of newline. If a \newline pair appears, and the backslash
>   itself is not quoted, the \newline is treated as a line continuation
>   (that is, it is removed from the input stream and effectively
>   ignored).

So when you say

```
something + \ + <new line> + another_thing
```

Bash converts it into

```
something + another_thing
```

#### What can you do, then?

Add a backslash and then start writing from the very beginning on the next line:

```
mkdir -p "$DEST_ROOT_PATH/"{"$DEST_DIR1",\
"$DEST_DIR2",\
...,\
"$DEST_DIRN"}
```

#### Some examples

When you say:

```
$ echo "ha"{a,b\
>    c}
ha{a,b c}
```

And then move the arrow up you'll see this is the command that was performed:

```
$ echo "ha"{a,b   c}
```

So just say:

```
$ echo "ha"{a,b\
> c}
haa habc
```

And you'll see this when moving up:

```
$ echo "ha"{a,b,c}
```

Another example:

```
$ cat touch_files.sh
touch X{1,\
2,3}
$ bash touch_files.sh
$ ls X*
X1 X2 X3
```

Comment: I think they already knew that. `but space alignement breaks the expansion :`

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui. I guessed what was going on (just needed a nice trick),  but it's useful to quote the official documentation for further readings.

Comment: @Amessihel glad this was useful. I initially understood your question as a _why?_, so when noticing it was _how?_ I decided to document very well the _why_ part. 123's trick is quite nice!

Answer (score 2):

Thus I accepted @123's answer, here's the one I choosed :

```
mkdir -p "$DEST_ROOT_PATH/"{"$DEST_DIR1","$DEST_DIR2"}
mkdir -p "$DEST_ROOT_PATH/"{"$DEST_DIR3","$DEST_DIR4"}
```

There are not a lot of destination directories here, so I think it's a good balance between the fancy-and-disgusting hack and the frustrating backslash which breaks the indentation.

Comment: You can maybe consider using an array to store such values and then loop through them.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it is follows (though it only addresses your particular task of creating multiple directories and doesn't answer the question as stated in the title):

```
for d in \
      "$DEST_DIR1" \
      "$DEST_DIR2" \
       ...         \
      "$DEST_DIRn" \
      ;
do
    mkdir -p "$DEST_ROOT_PATH/$d"
done
```

The advantage of this approach is that maintaining the list is a little easier.

In general, you should stop sticking to syntactic sugar when you notice that it starts causing inconveniences.