# How to deal with long strings and still get a well formatted code in bash?

Tags: string, bash, indentation

This one is kinda related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814739/how-to-write-fancy-indented-multi-line-brace-expansion-in-bash/37815564). Now I'm dealing with a long string:

```
sed -b -i.old $inifile \
    -e "s/a_very_long_pattern_i_should_problably_improve/terribly_long_replace_string"
```

Is there a way to get it well formatted (ie indented and not larger than 80 characters)? Use of backslashes adds extra-spaces:

```
$ echo 'first_part'\
>      'second_part'
first_part second_part
```

Comment: Wont the answer shown in the other question work here as well?

Comment: try an editor with that feature.

Comment: @andlrc, if you're talking about the "disgusting and clever hack", I won't use it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use printf to paste together a bunch of arguments:

```
sed -b -i.old $inifile \
    -e "$(printf %s
       's/long long pattern'
        '/long long replacement/;'
       's/another/command/'
       )"
```

Comment: Approved, sounds like it's the least dirty solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo 'first_part'\
>      'second_part'
first_part second_part
```

Bash concatenates string literals that are adjacent.

So for example if you had `echo "first_part" "second_part"` you would get

`first_part second_part`

But, if you had `echo "first_part""second_part"` you would get `first_partsecond_part`

so to take advantage of that for your

```
   -e "s/a_very_long_pattern_i_should_problably_improve/terribly_long_replace_string"
```

You could try doing something like

```
sed -b -i.old $inifile \  
    -e "s/a_very_long_pattern_"
                   "i_should_problably_improve/"
                   "terribly_long_replace_string"
```

Comment: Wait, you mean that `-e` parameter would concatenate all following args ?

Comment: It's _my_ sed command. :) I see what you mean, I prefer avoiding this hack, as said above.